# Remove Double Quotes from around JSON object - JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a form that is serialized and parsed into a JSON string. One of the form fields is a hidden field which contains a JSON object. I use the following function from another tutorial to transform my form data:

```
$.fn.serializeObject = function()
{
    var o = {};
    var a = this.serializeArray();
    $.each(a, function() {
        if (o[this.name] !== undefined) {
            if (!o[this.name].push) {
                o[this.name] = [o[this.name]];
            }
            o[this.name].push(this.value || '');
        } else {
            o[this.name] = this.value || '';
        }
    });
    return o;
};
```

This works great except my hidden field containing JSON is wrapped in double quotes, which doesn't bind when coming back  to my controller. If I manually removed the double quotes everything works well.

**Comes across as:**

```
{"Package":"[{"Qty":"15"}]","Fname":"test name"}
```

**Needs to be:**

```
{"Package":[{"Qty":"15"}],"Fname":"test name"}
```

How could I modify the above function to account for this?

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

Accounted for this in a new version of the function:

```
$.fn.serializeObject = function () {
                    var o = {};
                    var a = this.serializeArray();
                    $.each(a, function () {
                        if (o[this.name] !== undefined) {
                            if (!o[this.name].push) {
                                o[this.name] = [o[this.name]];
                            }
                            o[this.name].push(this.value || '');
                        } else {
                            if (this.value.charAt(0) == "[") {
                                o[this.name] = JSON.parse(this.value);
                            }
                            else {
                                o[this.name] = this.value || '';
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    return o;
                };
```

Comment: How are you populating the hidden field?  That's probably the best place to look to solve this issue

Comment: When the function serializeArray() is run it will take my form elements and wrap them all in double quotes as "name": "value"
, so I believe that's where the double quotes are coming from. It's fine for all other fields except the json object.

Answer (score 1):

Enclose your call to `serializeObject` with [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) instead, it should make sure the JSON is valid i.e.

```
var json = JSON.stringify(form.serializeObject());
```

Comment: I am running that command and it doesn't seem to be cleaning it up. See fiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/sxGtM/4090/

Comment: @Will I would say your real problem here is you are trying to add the JSON in as a string, but it should be treated as a literal i.e. `"[{'Qty':'15'}]"` is an array so it has to be converted first and then pushed. That's a very specific part of your parsing code therefore I can't think of a general solution to modify your `serializeObject` function - unless you added some extra attribute you could inspect to determine whether it's inline JSON e.g. `<input type="hidden" data-json="true" .../>`.

Comment: found a solution, see edit in my original post. I appreciate the help.

Comment: @Will that was what I had in mind, however, I was thinking of a more general solution - one which could be used in any circumstance. With your solution strings like "[Please select an option]" would be treated as JSON literals - however, it's what works for you.

Comment: That's a good point. How would I be able to utilize an attribute of input, such as data-json, within that function? When I get the data back from serializeArray() its in name/value format.